Calling own C++ template function in dylib ends up in identical one in other dylib on Mac
(Note: this is a major revision of the original question after I gained the insight that the original question was a red herring -- it didn't have any answers yet anyway.)
I'm working on an OSX host application, together with a set of dylib plugins for it.  The app loads these dylibs with dlopen.  Big parts of the code inside the plugins is identical (it comes from a shared static lib), and it contains several template functions (that are also specialized equally in all plugins).
However, if I load two of these plugins at the same time, and if these calls use one of the template functions, the second loaded plugin will not call it's own template function but calls the one from the first loaded plugin!?!  For normal functions everything works as expected (each dylib using it's own one).
In my case (see original question) this template function receives a pointer-to-base and does a dynamic_cast on it casting it to a derived type that is specified as a template argument.  But when the second plugin ends up in the first plugin's version of this template function, the rtti information there (esp. the typeid.hash_code()) for that template argument is different in the first plugin as compared to the incoming pointer-to-base-but-actually-derived argument from the second, and so dynamic_cast just returns nullptr.
I've tried all sorts of things to get a grip on what is causing this;

In my original MRE I tried to show that dynamic_cast issue, and noticed that if I inlined the derived class's virtual function in the .h, the problem went away for that template call.
In that example turning compiler optimizations on also 'fixed' it.
In that example switching over from RTLD_GLOBAL to RTLD_LOCAL also fixed it (note: local is the default on Linux, but on Mac it's global -- make sure you read the correct man pages).
I've also tried loading the dylib and accessing it's functions using CFBundleCreate i.c.w. CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName, but that didn't fix the issue either (I recon it probably also just uses dlopen behind the scenes).
Unloading the first plugin before loading the second one also fixes this, but that is not my use case.
These plugins already run under a certain 3rd party host application, and there this all works flawlessly...  How do they load us there?

While the above 'fixes' worked in the original MRE, they do not work in my actual code base, so it seems these are just symptoms of an underlying deeper issue.  What could be going on here?  I've tested this using Xcode 12.3 with clang 12.0.0 on OSX 11.4 (Big Sur) on an Intel x64, as well as Xcode 14.2 on OSX 13.1 (Ventura) on an ARM 64 m1.  And I'm using c++11 std compliant mode, but c++17 didn't make a difference either IIRC (funny the project files list c++0x though).
I'm... lost with this one. I've listed an updated MRE below.  On my machine the accompanying 'inside' and 'outside' printfs always list the same function address, and for the second plugin's TemplateFunction I get the address of the first plugin's version repeated.
pluginMain.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

template <typename T>
void TemplateFunction(T& arg) {
    arg = T{0};
    printf("inside;  template addr: %p\n", TemplateFunction<T>);
}

void NormalFunction(int& arg) {
    arg = int{0};
    printf("inside;  normal addr:   %p\n", NormalFunction);
}

extern "C" __attribute__((visibility("default"))) void Start() {
    int x;
    printf("outside; template addr: %p\n", TemplateFunction<int>);
    TemplateFunction(x);
    printf("outside; normal addr:   %p\n", NormalFunction);
    NormalFunction(x);
}

appMain.mm
(note: Objective-C file to make accessing the plugin bundles easier, but just using plain C++ with dlopen makes no difference.)
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <mach-o/dyld.h>
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <vector>

constexpr int dylibLoadMode = RTLD_NOW;
//constexpr int dylibLoadMode = RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL;

int main() {
    NSFileManager* localFileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString* pluginFolderPath = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL] URLByDeletingLastPathComponent] path];
    NSArray* folderEntries = [localFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pluginFolderPath error:nil];
    
    std::vector<void*> dylibHandles;
    int pluginNr = 0;
    for (NSString* folderEntry in folderEntries) {
        if ([folderEntry hasSuffix:@".plugin"]) {
            NSBundle* pluginBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[pluginFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:folderEntry]];

            NSString* pluginBinaryPath = [pluginBundle executablePath];
            void* dylibHandle = dlopen([pluginBinaryPath UTF8String], dylibLoadMode);
            if (dylibHandle != nullptr) {
                dylibHandles.push_back(dylibHandle);
                pluginNr++;

                using StartType = void(*)();
                StartType Start = (StartType)dlsym(dylibHandle, "Start");
                if (Start != nullptr) {
                    printf("plugin %d: %s\n", pluginNr, [folderEntry UTF8String]);
                    Start();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto& dylibHandle : dylibHandles)
        dlclose(dylibHandle);
}

Plugins project project.pbxproj
(note: it refs the upcoming App project as a dependency; keep that in mind when recreating these project files.)
// !$*UTF8*$!
{
    archiveVersion = 1;
    classes = {
    };
    objectVersion = 53;
    objects = {

/* Begin PBXBuildFile section */
        C365D6FD2C4FF21000F5F94C /* pluginMain.cpp in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = C365D6F92C4FF21000F5F94C /* pluginMain.cpp */; };
        C365D6FE2C4FF21000F5F94C /* pluginMain.cpp in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = C365D6F92C4FF21000F5F94C /* pluginMain.cpp */; };
/* End PBXBuildFile section */

/* Begin PBXContainerItemProxy section */
        C3D27D702C4FF838006CECB3 /* PBXContainerItemProxy */ = {
            isa = PBXContainerItemProxy;
            containerPortal = C3D27D6C2C4FF838006CECB3 /* App.xcodeproj */;
            proxyType = 2;
            remoteGlobalIDString = C354668B2861AACA00B88767;
            remoteInfo = App;
        };
        C3D27D782C4FF896006CECB3 /* PBXContainerItemProxy */ = {
            isa = PBXContainerItemProxy;
            containerPortal = C3D27D6C2C4FF838006CECB3 /* App.xcodeproj */;
            proxyType = 1;
            remoteGlobalIDString = C354668A2861AACA00B88767;
            remoteInfo = App;
        };
        C3D27D7A2C4FF89D006CECB3 /* PBXContainerItemProxy */ = {
            isa = PBXContainerItemProxy;
            containerPortal = C3D27D6C2C4FF838006CECB3 /* App.xcodeproj */;
            proxyType = 1;
            remoteGlobalIDString = C354668A2861AACA00B88767;
            remoteInfo = App;
        };
/* End PBXContainerItemProxy section */

/* Begin PBXFileReference section */
        3CCFCD5322258EA8007B2590 /* Plugin2.plugin */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; explicitFileType = wrapper.cfbundle; includeInIndex = 0; path = Plugin2.plugin; sourceTree = BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR; };
        C321AA982655298D008167A4 /* Plugin1.plugin */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; explicitFileType = wrapper.cfbundle; includeInIndex = 0; path = Plugin1.plugin; sourceTree = BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR; };
        C365D6F92C4FF21000F5F94C /* pluginMain.cpp */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; fileEncoding = 4; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.cpp.cpp; path = pluginMain.cpp; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
        C3D27D6C2C4FF838006CECB3 /* App.xcodeproj */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = "wrapper.pb-project"; path = App.xcodeproj; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
/* End PBXFileReference section */

/* Begin PBXGroup section */
        3C26733C219099730091C684 = {
            isa = PBXGroup;
            children = (
                C3D27D6C2C4FF838006CECB3 /* App.xcodeproj */,
                C365D6F92C4FF21000F5F94C /* pluginMain.cpp */,
                3C267346219099730091C684 /* Products */,
            );
            sourceTree = "<group>";
        };
        3C267346219099730091C684 /* Products */ = {
            isa = PBXGroup;
            children = (
                3CCFCD5322258EA8007B2590 /* Plugin2.plugin */,
                C321AA982655298D008167A4 /* Plugin1.plugin */,
            );
            name = Products;
            sourceTree = "<group>";
        };
        C3D27D6D2C4FF838006CECB3 /* Products */ = {
            isa = PBXGroup;
            children = (
                C3D27D712C4FF838006CECB3 /* App.app */,
            );
            name = Products;
            sourceTree = "<group>";
        };
/* End PBXGroup section */

/* Begin PBXNativeTarget section */
        3CCFCD3322258EA8007B2590 /* Plugin2 */ = {
            isa = PBXNativeTarget;
            buildConfigurationList = 3CCFCD5022258EA8007B2590 /* Build configuration list for PBXNativeTarget "Plugin2" */;
            buildPhases = (
                3CCFCD3622258EA8007B2590 /* Sources */,
            );
            buildRules = (
            );
            dependencies = (
                C3D27D7B2C4FF89D006CECB3 /* PBXTargetDependency */,
            );
            name = Plugin2;
            productName = "${TARGET_NAME}";
            productReference = 3CCFCD5322258EA8007B2590 /* Plugin2.plugin */;
            productType = "com.apple.product-type.bundle";
        };
        C321AA7A2655298D008167A4 /* Plugin1 */ = {
            isa = PBXNativeTarget;
            buildConfigurationList = C321AA952655298D008167A4 /* Build configuration list for PBXNativeTarget "Plugin1" */;
            buildPhases = (
                C321AA7D2655298D008167A4 /* Sources */,
            );
            buildRules = (
            );
            dependencies = (
                C3D27D792C4FF896006CECB3 /* PBXTargetDependency */,
            );
            name = Plugin1;
            productName = "${TARGET_NAME}";
            productReference = C321AA982655298D008167A4 /* Plugin1.plugin */;
            productType = "com.apple.product-type.bundle";
        };
/* End PBXNativeTarget section */

/* Begin PBXProject section */
        3C26733D219099730091C684 /* Project object */ = {
            isa = PBXProject;
            attributes = {
                BuildIndependentTargetsInParallel = YES;
                LastUpgradeCheck = 1430;
                ORGANIZATIONNAME = "MyOrg";
                TargetAttributes = {
                    3CCFCD3322258EA8007B2590 = {
                        ProvisioningStyle = Manual;
                    };
                    C321AA7A2655298D008167A4 = {
                        ProvisioningStyle = Manual;
                    };
                };
            };
            buildConfigurationList = 3C267340219099730091C684 /* Build configuration list for PBXProject "Plugins" */;
            compatibilityVersion = "Xcode 8.0";
            developmentRegion = en;
            hasScannedForEncodings = 0;
            knownRegions = (
                en,
                Base,
            );
            mainGroup = 3C26733C219099730091C684;
            productRefGroup = 3C267346219099730091C684 /* Products */;
            projectDirPath = "";
            projectReferences = (
                {
                    ProductGroup = C3D27D6D2C4FF838006CECB3 /* Products */;
                    ProjectRef = C3D27D6C2C4FF838006CECB3 /* App.xcodeproj */;
                },
            );
            projectRoot = "";
            targets = (
                C321AA7A2655298D008167A4 /* Plugin1 */,
                3CCFCD3322258EA8007B2590 /* Plugin2 */,
            );
        };
/* End PBXProject section */

/* Begin PBXReferenceProxy section */
        C3D27D712C4FF838006CECB3 /* App.app */ = {
            isa = PBXReferenceProxy;
            fileType = wrapper.application;
            path = App.app;
            remoteRef = C3D27D702C4FF838006CECB3 /* PBXContainerItemProxy */;
            sourceTree = BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR;
        };
/* End PBXReferenceProxy section */

/* Begin PBXSourcesBuildPhase section */
        3CCFCD3622258EA8007B2590 /* Sources */ = {
            isa = PBXSourcesBuildPhase;
            buildActionMask = 2147483647;
            files = (
                C365D6FE2C4FF21000F5F94C /* pluginMain.cpp in Sources */,
            );
            runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 0;
        };
        C321AA7D2655298D008167A4 /* Sources */ = {
            isa = PBXSourcesBuildPhase;
            buildActionMask = 2147483647;
            files = (
                C365D6FD2C4FF21000F5F94C /* pluginMain.cpp in Sources */,
            );
            runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 0;
        };
/* End PBXSourcesBuildPhase section */

/* Begin PBXTargetDependency section */
        C3D27D792C4FF896006CECB3 /* PBXTargetDependency */ = {
            isa = PBXTargetDependency;
            name = App;
            targetProxy = C3D27D782C4FF896006CECB3 /* PBXContainerItemProxy */;
        };
        C3D27D7B2C4FF89D006CECB3 /* PBXTargetDependency */ = {
            isa = PBXTargetDependency;
            name = App;
            targetProxy = C3D27D7A2C4FF89D006CECB3 /* PBXContainerItemProxy */;
        };
/* End PBXTargetDependency section */

/* Begin XCBuildConfiguration section */
        C35468692861AE1C00B88767 /* Debug */ = {
            isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
            buildSettings = {
                CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = "c++0x";
                CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY = "libc++";
                CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = "$(PROJECT_DIR)/bin";
                ENABLE_TESTABILITY = YES;
                FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                    "$(inherited)",
                    "$(LOCAL_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks",
                );
                GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = 0;
                GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = "DEBUG=1";
                GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN = YES;
                INFOPLIST_FILE = "${PROJECT_DIR}/pluginInfo.plist";
                MACH_O_TYPE = mh_bundle;
                MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.15;
                ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES;
                PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = "com.test.$(PRODUCT_NAME)";
                PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";
                PRODUCT_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";
                SDKROOT = macosx;
                VALID_ARCHS = "x86_64 arm64";
                WRAPPER_EXTENSION = plugin;
            };
            name = Debug;
        };
        C354687C2861AE1C00B88767 /* Debug */ = {
            isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
            buildSettings = {
            };
            name = Debug;
        };
        C35468872861AE1C00B88767 /* Debug */ = {
            isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
            buildSettings = {
            };
            name = Debug;
        };
/* End XCBuildConfiguration section */

/* Begin XCConfigurationList section */
        3C267340219099730091C684 /* Build configuration list for PBXProject "Plugins" */ = {
            isa = XCConfigurationList;
            buildConfigurations = (
                C35468692861AE1C00B88767 /* Debug */,
            );
            defaultConfigurationIsVisible = 0;
            defaultConfigurationName = Debug;
        };
        3CCFCD5022258EA8007B2590 /* Build configuration list for PBXNativeTarget "Plugin2" */ = {
            isa = XCConfigurationList;
            buildConfigurations = (
                C35468872861AE1C00B88767 /* Debug */,
            );
            defaultConfigurationIsVisible = 0;
            defaultConfigurationName = Debug;
        };
        C321AA952655298D008167A4 /* Build configuration list for PBXNativeTarget "Plugin1" */ = {
            isa = XCConfigurationList;
            buildConfigurations = (
                C354687C2861AE1C00B88767 /* Debug */,
            );
            defaultConfigurationIsVisible = 0;
            defaultConfigurationName = Debug;
        };
/* End XCConfigurationList section */
    };
    rootObject = 3C26733D219099730091C684 /* Project object */;
}

App project's project.pbxproj
// !$*UTF8*$!
{
    archiveVersion = 1;
    classes = {
    };
    objectVersion = 53;
    objects = {

/* Begin PBXBuildFile section */
        C365D70B2C4FF23200F5F94C /* appMain.mm in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = C365D70A2C4FF23200F5F94C /* appMain.mm */; };
/* End PBXBuildFile section */

/* Begin PBXFileReference section */
        C354668B2861AACA00B88767 /* App.app */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; explicitFileType = wrapper.application; includeInIndex = 0; path = App.app; sourceTree = BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR; };
        C365D70A2C4FF23200F5F94C /* appMain.mm */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; fileEncoding = 4; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.cpp.objcpp; path = appMain.mm; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
/* End PBXFileReference section */

/* Begin PBXGroup section */
        3C26733C219099730091C684 = {
            isa = PBXGroup;
            children = (
                C365D70A2C4FF23200F5F94C /* appMain.mm */,
                3C267346219099730091C684 /* Products */,
            );
            sourceTree = "<group>";
        };
        3C267346219099730091C684 /* Products */ = {
            isa = PBXGroup;
            children = (
                C354668B2861AACA00B88767 /* App.app */,
            );
            name = Products;
            sourceTree = "<group>";
        };
/* End PBXGroup section */

/* Begin PBXNativeTarget section */
        C354668A2861AACA00B88767 /* App */ = {
            isa = PBXNativeTarget;
            buildConfigurationList = C354669C2861AACB00B88767 /* Build configuration list for PBXNativeTarget "App" */;
            buildPhases = (
                C35466872861AACA00B88767 /* Sources */,
            );
            buildRules = (
            );
            dependencies = (
            );
            name = App;
            productName = "${TARGET_NAME}";
            productReference = C354668B2861AACA00B88767 /* App.app */;
            productType = "com.apple.product-type.application";
        };
/* End PBXNativeTarget section */

/* Begin PBXProject section */
        3C26733D219099730091C684 /* Project object */ = {
            isa = PBXProject;
            attributes = {
                BuildIndependentTargetsInParallel = YES;
                LastUpgradeCheck = 1430;
                ORGANIZATIONNAME = "MyOrg";
                TargetAttributes = {
                    C354668A2861AACA00B88767 = {
                        CreatedOnToolsVersion = 12.3;
                    };
                };
            };
            buildConfigurationList = 3C267340219099730091C684 /* Build configuration list for PBXProject "App" */;
            compatibilityVersion = "Xcode 8.0";
            developmentRegion = en;
            hasScannedForEncodings = 0;
            knownRegions = (
                en,
                Base,
            );
            mainGroup = 3C26733C219099730091C684;
            productRefGroup = 3C267346219099730091C684 /* Products */;
            projectDirPath = "";
            projectRoot = "";
            targets = (
                C354668A2861AACA00B88767 /* App */,
            );
        };
/* End PBXProject section */

/* Begin PBXSourcesBuildPhase section */
        C35466872861AACA00B88767 /* Sources */ = {
            isa = PBXSourcesBuildPhase;
            buildActionMask = 2147483647;
            files = (
                C365D70B2C4FF23200F5F94C /* appMain.mm in Sources */,
            );
            runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 0;
        };
/* End PBXSourcesBuildPhase section */

/* Begin XCBuildConfiguration section */
        C35468692861AE1C00B88767 /* Debug */ = {
            isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
            buildSettings = {
                CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = "c++0x";
                CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY = "libc++";
                CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = "$(PROJECT_DIR)/bin";
                ENABLE_TESTABILITY = YES;
                GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = 0;
                GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = "DEBUG=1";
                GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN = YES;
                INFOPLIST_FILE = "${PROJECT_DIR}/appInfo.plist";
                MACH_O_TYPE = mh_execute;
                MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.15;
                ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES;
                PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = "com.test.$(PRODUCT_NAME)";
                PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";
                PRODUCT_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";
                SDKROOT = macosx;
                VALID_ARCHS = "x86_64 arm64";
            };
            name = Debug;
        };
        C35468DC2861AE1C00B88767 /* Debug */ = {
            isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
            buildSettings = {
            };
            name = Debug;
        };
/* End XCBuildConfiguration section */

/* Begin XCConfigurationList section */
        3C267340219099730091C684 /* Build configuration list for PBXProject "App" */ = {
            isa = XCConfigurationList;
            buildConfigurations = (
                C35468692861AE1C00B88767 /* Debug */,
            );
            defaultConfigurationIsVisible = 0;
            defaultConfigurationName = Debug;
        };
        C354669C2861AACB00B88767 /* Build configuration list for PBXNativeTarget "App" */ = {
            isa = XCConfigurationList;
            buildConfigurations = (
                C35468DC2861AE1C00B88767 /* Debug */,
            );
            defaultConfigurationIsVisible = 0;
            defaultConfigurationName = Debug;
        };
/* End XCConfigurationList section */
    };
    rootObject = 3C26733D219099730091C684 /* Project object */;
}

pluginInfo.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>BNDL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright.</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
</plist>

appInfo.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>$(MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET)</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright.</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
</dict>
</plist>


seems to compile and run fine: https://godbolt.org/z/5a9qb8WTb

"This code now fails" is not a real issue description. What do you take for failure?

Thank you for supplying a [mcve].  Alas, it appears to work correctly for me on my machine (as I see it did for Oersted as well, using Matt Godbolt's Compiler Explorer).

@3CxEZiVlQ: the dynamic_cast in the templated function fails and returns a nullptr, while the identical dynamic_cast outside the template function does the thing it's supposed to do.

@Oersted: thanks for that godbolt setup.  I thought about that too but had an appointment I needed to go to so was a bit out time for that.  Looking at it I spotted another detail: it is indeed a debug build that's acting up.  I'll check if release builds have this issue too tomorrow (manager priorities permitting that is).

Behavior is the same with Release configuration.

I've looked at it a bit further by stripping our entire code base to a minimal void main while still exhibiting this issue, and: it indeed looks like a compiler bug of sorts, but it's related to having the code inside a dylib and loading 2 or more (identical versions) of them concurrently; calling the test code in the 2nd exhibits this issue, but only when optimizations are turned off (who would have thought).  I'll try to botch up a proper over-complete MRE including Xcode project files and all and keep you posted.

'Solved'! Though I'm not a mac/linux whizz, so I could be off. Irl, the code is located in a dylib bundle plugin, and 2+ of these plugins get loaded at the same time. I use dlopen with RTLD_NOW (ctrl c+v), which should imply RTLD_LOCAL, but it seems RTLD_GLOBAL got used instead? Using RTLD_LOCAL fixes the issue. The man says RTLD_GLOBAL puts the dylib symbols in one global namespace (right?), so I assume the 2nd+ loaded plugin (with identical classes) will cause a clash in the registered rtti info, giving dynamic_cast a hard time. So the optimization level might have been a red herring here.

I found that the typeid hash_code inside and outside the template function when executing the 2nd loaded plugin are different; the 2nd one uses the template function from the 1st loaded plugin instead of it's own?! If I make it a regular function this doesn't happen. I assume dlopen remaps function pointers to the dylib's loaded address range, and that this is where the clash occurs? But why would a template function behave differently... questions galore. I'll brood on this a bit more; if someone can shed more light on this I'm all ears. But it's all unrelated to the original question by now.

I want to give a big thanks for everyone that helped me out with this though, even if we were all barking up the wrong tree :)

Right.  I've spent another day on this and found out dynamic_cast / rtti was a red herring indeed.  The actual issue is one dylib ending up in another one's template function...  I've overhauled the original question to reflect this.  Or should I just have made another question, deleting this one?  Didn't seem fair to the above helpful people though...

Different shared objects shouldn't export functions with the same name. Make these symbols static, or restrict their visibility to the containing shared object (with gcc it is __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden"))))

@LorinczyZsigmond That should work too, but the shared static lib literally contains thousands upon thousands of objects.  Marking them all 'hidden' by hand is undoable, and isn't necessary on Windows either, not when loaded by another host app on Mac, which tells me there should be another way.  Weird thing is that using RTLD_LOCAL is enough for disambiguating normal functions (each dylib calling it's own version), but not for template functions.

Well, the very first problem is the shared static lib. It should be a shared shared lib. (The other mean problem is C++, it is known to be icompatible with dynamic loading.)

@LorinczyZsigmond and there is where the problem lies: these dylibs are meant to be 100% self-contained :)

Off: in carefully designed systems (e.g. httpd, perl, python), there is common shared lib used by both the main executable and the plugins, so it is safe to link the plugins against this shared lib.

And I solved it after another day of elbow grease.
It was a combination of both the template function and the normal function being exported in the dylib too, but while using RTLD_LOCAL with dlopen effectively sandboxed the dylibs into calling their own normal function, this didn't happen for the template function.  Reasons still unknown, but in my case I do not want to export these internal functions at all anyway, only a select few I already explicitly marked with __attribute__((visibility("default"))).  It also turned out that Xcode has a setting named 'Enable Testability' that is set to Yes for debug builds, but which acts as a kill switch for all symbol stripping whatsoever -- not knowing about that was a rabbit hole in an of itself.
What it all boils down to is that my Xcode project now has:

"Build Options \ Enable Testability" set to "No", also for Debug builds.  In my case there are no external unit tests anyway, but I do want to be able to load 2 or more of these plugins simultaneously.
"Deployment \ Deployment Postprocessing" set to "Yes", since this seems to be needed to even enable the symbol stripping phase.
"Deployment \ Strip Style" set to "Non-Global Symbols", but this alone didn't prove to be sufficient.
"Linking \ Exported Symbols File" to a txt file with the names of the symbols I want to export.  Not doing so still caused e.g. the symbols of an external 3rd party static lib to be re-exported by my dylibs too.
"Apple Clang - Code Generation \ Symbols Hidden by Default" to "Yes", as a starting point.
"Apple Clang - Custom Compiler Flags \ Other C++ Flags" to "-fVisibility=hidden", to put a nail into that coffin too.

If anyone still has a clue as to why these template functions clashed even though I used RTLD_LOCAL, please post that as an answer too, since in my opinion that shouldn't even happen at all.  And if my config list above is overkill, please share.
